# How to create, build and run a multi ASP.NET Core project in a single folder VsCode workspace?

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

How do I create, build and run multiple ASP.NET Core projects in a single folder in a VS Code workspace, for a repository that has a single startup project and one or more class libraries?

The documentation for multiple-root workspaces states that it is useful when dealing with multiple projects that are not stored in the same parent folder. Projects stored in the same repository though *are* all stored in the same parent folder, so how do I handle that situation in the simplest way, ideally without having to use multi-root workspaces, and ideally in a manner that is amenable to running in a dev container.

I've looked through the VS Code documentation and don't see anything about this at all, and Googling just turns up a few blogs from years ago that look quite out-of-date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no documentation because 'it just works'.

Using VsCode you can open a folder in a dev container using an ASP Core 5 image. Manually create a folder at the workspace root and create an ASP Core project in that folder using `dotnet new webapi`. Run using `dotnet run` and after generating a dev certificate the service is accessible from outside the container.

Manually create a new subfolder at the workspace root and create a class library project in that folder using `dotnet new classlib`. Build it using `dotnet build`.

Reference the classlib from the service using `dotnet add reference ../project2.csproj`.

Two very nice bonuses.

1. Running `dotnet watch run` on the service project will detect and build changes in both the service and the dependency.
2. Generating a default debug configuration in VsCode will attach to the running service (once you locate the correct process), and will step into the dependency project too with no additional configuration required.